# Perform an action in JavaScript when an id hits the top of a browser viewport

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I'm working on creating a button that sends a customer to the review field in Woocommerce using the `scrollIntoView()` function in Javascript.

I'm also working on hiding and showing the button when the reviews section comes into the viewport, and it's working, but I want to take it a step further. The button as soon as the bottom of the browser hits the ID, which I don't want. I want the button to show when the ID hits the top of the browser.

Here's the basic HTML:

```
<button onClick="scrollToComment()" id="scroll-btn">Leave a Review</button>

<div id="reviews">

  //a bunch of reviews and comments go here

  <div id="review_form"></div>

</div>
```

Here is the JS:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    var element = document.querySelector('#reviews');
    var position = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    var scrollBtn = document.querySelector('#scroll-btn');

     if(position.top < window.innerHeight && position.bottom >= 0) {

        scrollBtn.style.display = 'block';
    }

    else {

        scrollBtn.style.display = 'none';

    }
});


function scrollToComment() {
    var button = document.querySelector('#review_form');
    button.scrollIntoView();

}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why won't you just test against the position of the frame when it hits the top ?

```js
// if position.top is between -1 and 1 it means it's on top
// don't use '=== 0' to avoid pixel perfect glitches
if (position.top > -1 && position.top < 1) {
  scrollBtn.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm a newb at using vanilla JS. Would I use that if statement instead of the if statement I already coded?

Comment: @Sackadelic yes and keep the else condition. Try it and tell me if this is what you want.

Comment: @Sackadelic Sorry I reversed the conditional signs, try it again.

Comment: Thanks for your help, this seems to work, but I need to debug it. The button appears for one pixed and It disappears immediately.

Comment: How would you keep it visible for the entire div? There are many reviews in this div and I would like to keep it visible the entire time the div is in the viewport, just start when the div hits the top of the viewport. Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks @vdegenne I was able to accomplish this with `position.top < -1 && position.top < 1 `

Answer (score 0):

Use [IntersectionObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API).

```
var observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);
```

Comment: I was under the assumption that this is still an experimental feature, do you think It is safe to use?

Comment: Of course, I'v seen many infinite scroll packages using this api. Meanwhile I'v used it in an enterprise chat application and everything is fine :)